# How can I get Unity to display applications when pressing start key?

Tags: unity, 15.10

Currently, in order to to get to the to installed application list, I have to at least click 3 times. I want to shorten this process to only one click. I would like go straight to the Unity installed application list when I press the start key.

Comment: Super+A, most shorcuts are showed if you hold Super for a seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install unity, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

To install gnome-shell, do the same in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

You can choose the default login manager as per your preference.